# Powershell console control

Tags: wpf, powershell

Does anybody know of a console control that I can use to host a Powershell console in my WPF app?
I have a WPF app that is scriptable with Powershell, and I want to allow the user to open up a PS console to type some commands.

Comment: HI Nestor, did you ever find anything? looking for the same

Comment: http://www.powerwf.com/ were going to publish a control... but I don't know if they did.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this project:

http://poshconsole.codeplex.com/

Its a WPF based console. You can download the source and check it out.

http://poshconsole.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Comment: Yeah... I've done that. That's my best option so far... but there are several bugs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces Pipeline object to interact with a hosted powershell runspace programmatically, you can bind the input commands and output to any controls of your choosing, such as a TextBox for input and a MultiLine textblock for output or some fancier controls as you like.

Here's a link to the CreatePipeline API doc:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.createpipeline(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm looking for a full featured console, with tab completion, implementation of Write-Host etc